# CSS Grid span but same height as a cell

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to have a css grid as follows.

| A | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 4 | 5 | 6 |
|  | 7 | 8 |  |

**A** is like the header and numbers (1 to 8) are data that comes from an API. I want to have A as the same height as numbers so I cannot use `grid-row: 1/-1`. I don't want to add an empty cell in every 4th item because I'm using AlpineJS x-for and it only supports only one child element.

```css
body {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 2rem auto;
}

.tier-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
  gap: 1rem;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
}

.card button {
  margin-top: auto;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: none;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
}

.btn:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.btn-primary {
  background: #6944CE;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.info {
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.info p {
  margin: auto;
}

.info-footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  background: #6944CE;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="tier-grid">
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Tier 1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore veritatis, excepturi, laudantium optio,
        molestiae quo cumque illo harum laborum dignissimos nisi ut et modi dolor minus ex dolores voluptate. Unde.</p>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</button>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Placeholder Image" />
      <span class="info-footer">Buy Now</span>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Placeholder Image" />
      <span class="info-footer">Buy Now</span>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Placeholder Image" />
      <span class="info-footer">Buy Now</span>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <p>I want this to be an empty cell.</p>
      <span class="info-footer">Buy Now</span>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Placeholder Image" />
      <span class="info-footer">Buy Now</span>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Placeholder Image" />
      <span class="info-footer">Buy Now</span>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Placeholder Image" />
      <span class="info-footer">Buy Now</span>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <p>I want this to be an empty cell.</p>
      <span class="info-footer">Buy Now</span>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Placeholder Image" />
      <span class="info-footer">Buy Now</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please add enough CSS and HTML so we can see your basic structure. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example will help you put the code direct into your question in such a way that we can run it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
.info:nth-child(3n) {
  border: 3px solid red;
  grid-column: 3;
}

.info:nth-child(3n+1) {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  grid-column: 4;
}

.info:nth-child(3n+2) {
  border: 3px solid green;
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

This will allow you to place the info items on your desired column without needing to add any extra "dummy" content element for the "empty cells"

```css
body {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 2rem auto;
}

.tier-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
  gap: 1rem;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
}

.card button {
  margin-top: auto;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: none;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
}

.btn:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.btn-primary {
  background: #6944CE;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.info {
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.info:nth-child(3n) {
  border: 3px solid red;
  grid-column: 3;
}

.info:nth-child(3n+1) {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  grid-column: 4;
}

.info:nth-child(3n+2) {
  border: 3px solid green;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.info p {
  margin: auto;
}

.info-footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  background: #6944CE;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="tier-grid">
  <div class="card">
    <h1>Tier 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore veritatis, excepturi, laudantium optio, molestiae quo cumque illo harum laborum dignissimos nisi ut et modi dolor minus ex dolores voluptate. Unde.</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    <span class="info-footer">Buy Now</span>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    <span class="info-footer">Buy Now</span>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    <span class="info-footer">Buy Now</span>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    <span class="info-footer">Buy Now</span>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    <span class="info-footer">Buy Now</span>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    <span class="info-footer">Buy Now</span>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    <span class="info-footer">Buy Now</span>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    <span class="info-footer">Buy Now</span>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    <span class="info-footer">Buy Now</span>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    <span class="info-footer">Buy Now</span>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    <span class="info-footer">Buy Now</span>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Placeholder Image" />
    <span class="info-footer">Buy Now</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm looking for this answer. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Does adding

```css
.card {
    ...
    grid-row: 1 / span 3;
}
```

get what you want? I'm trying to see if you can make this dynamic and just fill all the columns instead of specifying how many you have but I want to check first if this is in the right direction.

Comment: The problem is .info data is dynamic and it can be less than or more than 3 rows.